# How can I display Different MenuItems for Registered and Non-Registered Users in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, menu, sharedpreferences, menuitem

Below is the code to check whether user is logged in or not , so if user is logged then he will see "greeting-layout" else "registration-layout" .
According to user's status(registered/un-registered) I want to display different "menuItems" or "Menu" .
Do i need to make different Classes for registered and unregistered user ?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /* check User's "STATUS" is logged-in or not and display screen according to "STATUS"  */
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("CRUMBS",MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (prefs.getString("logged", "").toString().equals("logged")) {
        setContentView(R.layout.crumbs_view_logged);

        //Display menu items > " Logout " & " Profile "

    }else{

        setContentView(R.layout.crumbs_view_default);
        //Display menu items > "Register" & " Login " 

    }

}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just inflate different `menu.xml` files. A bit like

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
  if (loggedIn) {
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.registered,menu);
  }
  else {
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.nonRegistered,menu);
  }
  return true;
}
```

Where you have `res/menu/registered.xml` for registered users and `.../nonRegistered.xml` for others. For common menu items, you need to provide the same id.

Answer (score 0):

**You want something like this?**

```
package test;

class Main {
    protected void onCreate() {
        final IUser user;
        if ("logged".equals("logged")) {
            user = new RegisteredUser();
        } else {
            user = new UnRegisteredUser(); 
        }
        user.showMenu();
    }
}

public interface IUser {
    public void showMenu();
}

class RegisteredUser implements IUser {
    @Override
    public void showMenu() {
        //Display menu items > " Logout " & " Profile "
    }
}

class UnRegisteredUser implements IUser {
    @Override
    public void showMenu() {
        //Display menu items > "Register" & " Login "
    }
}
```